# Prove any set S of three integers contains a pair $x\neq y$ such that $x^3y-xy^3$ is divisible by 10.

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility, pigeonhole-principle

Prove any set S of three integers contains a pair $x\neq y$ such that $x^3y-xy^3$ is divisible by 10.

My attempt was :
By the division algorithm, every integer $n$ can be written as $n = 10q + r,$ where $0\leq r \leq 9$. Since there are three integers in $S$ but only 10 possible values for the remainder r. By the pigeonhole principle, the set S contains x & y that leave the same remainder on division by 10, that is there exist s with $0\leq s \leq 9$ such that $x = 10q_1 +s$ and $y = 10q_2+s.$ From here plug x and y into $x^3y-xy^3$ and show there is a 10 I can factor out.

Am I going about this problem the right way?

Comment: Seems like you have $3$ pigeons with $10$ holes...I mean, the set $S=\{1,2,3\}$ does not contain two values wih the same remainder under division by $10$.

Comment: Hints: (1) Factor $x^3 y - x y^3$. (2) Note that $x^3 y - x y^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$ iff $x^3 y - x y^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ and $x^3 y - x y^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach has been pointed out in the comments by **lulu**.

Note that $x^3y-xy^3=xy(x^2-y^2)=xy(x-y)(x+y)$.

- Show that at least one of the four factors must be even no matter what $x$ and $y$ are.

If $x$ or $y$ is a multiple of $5$, or if $x\equiv y\pmod5$, or if $x+y\equiv0\pmod 5$, then $x^3y-xy^3$ is a multiple of $10$. What combinations of $x$ and $y$ does that cover if neither is a multiple of $5$? Look at $x$ and $y$ modulo $5$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
x\backslash y&1&2&3&4\\\hline
1&\checkmark&&&\checkmark\\
2&&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
3&&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
4&\checkmark&&&\checkmark
\end{array}$$

- Show that any set of three integers must contain a multiple of $5$ or two integers in one of that form one of the covered combinations.